# How to access elements List values

Tags: java, list

I read a text file and each line I add to a `list`

```
List row = new ArrayList();
...
row.add(line);
```

Then I iterate trough List and each "record" I print like this:

```
System.out.println(row.get(i));
```

This statement returns

`[some, text, here]`

How can I access each string in here `[some, text, here]`?

Comment: Can you post more code? Specifically what `line` is would be very useful.

Comment: It looks like you've added an array of elements to the List, try casting the list to String[] or Object[], ie Object[] values = (Object[])row.get(i);

Answer (score 2):

I think you're reading [CSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-values) files so you can [split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) with the , as parameter for your return value to be like [some],[text],[here] then you'll have access to each of the words of the entire string.

Suppose you then want access to text you just use something like:

```
System.out.println(row.get(i)).split(',')[2];
```

P.S. If [ and ] are also a problem you can remove them by using first a [substring](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int%29) to use just the substring you need.